# Can not input or print Chinese on PuTTY

Tags: linux, putty, utf-8

On Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3,

I've set my environment variable as below

```
$ echo $LANG
zh_CN.UTF-8

$ echo $LANGUAGE
zh_CN.UTF-8

$ echo $SUPPORTED
en_US.UTF-8:en_US:en:zh_CN.UTF-8

$ locale
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

Meanwhile I've set PuTTY's transmission encoding as utf-8 and appearance->font setting to have a font as 'Fixedsys' which does support chinese.

However, when I try to print a file with Chinese, it can not print it correctly

```
$ cat 1.txt
hello▒▒▒ $
```

and I can not input Chinese correctly on shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `screen` you must start it with the `-U` option in order to have utf8 support.

It seems like `defutf8 on` in your `.screenrc` should do this for you, but it won't.

Comment: I'm not using screen; i tried to run screen -U and cat 1.txt, it's still not printing it.

Comment: @hetaoblog Not sure then.  The putty settings you've given allow me to produce Chinese characters if screen is not running, or with `screen -U`.  Are you running some other program like `tmux` (which uses `-u`)?

Comment: I'm not running tmux. i just login putty and do the settings. on my personal linux, i modified /etc/sysconfig/i18n to set LANG/LANGUAGE/SUPPORTED/SYSFONT to include chinese characters and it worked;  for the machine which i do not have permission to do so, I assume it should be fine to set the environment variables there. but it turned out not working...

Comment: @hetaoblog I think the best bet then is to try comparing `env` on both servers and figuring out what's different.  I use Debian and can't find any good docs on what exactly the settings in `/etc/sysconfig/i18n` *DO* and how they are used, and I'm not finding anything there that should interfere.  The settings in there don't seem to be environment variables though.  I found a webpage that suggests that you can have per-user i18n settings in `~/.i18n` so maybe you can try creating a file named that with those commands and logging out and back in again.

Comment: thx very much for your kind help. i tried to create the file but it did not work either.  the 2 servers are in 2 different environment that i can not access at the same time. I'll try to look for some other ways.  someone said i need to install something like 'zhcon' in order to support chinese, but this does not match with my personal experience on my personal linux server.

Comment: @hetaoblog Sorry I couldn't fix it. `zhcon` is for the local terminal display, not over ssh.

Comment: anyway thx very much for your kind help. so many times that I was moved by the many kind people like you on the SO network